# View [layouts.app] not found. Laravel Framework 5.4.36

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having a problem using Laravel Framework 5.4.36 (on Visual studio code). I am trying to build a simple layout, but no mater how much I've tried I am getting the same error on my browser :

> View [layouts.app] not found. (View: C:\wamp64\www\lsapp\resources\views\pages\services.blade.php)

as you can see (photo bellow) the file is deferentially there, in the right path.[image]

Here is my code for my layout app.blade.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{config('app.name','LSAPP')}}</title>
</head>
<body>
       @yield('content')
</body>
```

and here is my code from services.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
        <h1>services</h1>
        <p>This is the services page</p>
@endsection
```

I have also installed Laravel Blade Snippets v 1.13.0 (1.14.1 was giving me another problem).

I have tried to change name and path both to the layout file and inside the extends parameter. Any ideas why this is not working?

Thank you very much in advance for your help..!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must reference a blade template relative to the `resources/views` directory. According to the screenshot your directory structure is:

```
resources
  ↳views
    ↳pages
      ↳layouts
         app.blade.php
```

Therefore your `app.blade.php` layout is available as `pages.layouts.app`:

```
@extends('pages.layouts.app')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help..!!! This works..!!! I was searching for 3 hour before i post here..!! Again thank you .!!!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

To

```
@extends('pages.layouts.app')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you put 'layouts' folder inside 'pages', actually, it should be inside view only.

directory structure should be:

```
-view
    -layouts
    -pages
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the aforementioned answers. Because there might be cases where these answers do not solve your problems (mostly when you are not on a local server, and live).

Remember that namespacing is case-sensitive (especially while live). Therefore, when creating an extension of a file in the layouts folder as seen in the `service.blade.php` file as listed below:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>services</h1>
    <p>This is the services page</p>
@endsection
```

Do make sure the letter-casing for the layouts folder is spelt exactly the same as wherever you would be referencing it.

For instance:
If your layouts folder was created with the nametag `Layouts` and you are trying to access this folder in the `service.blade.php` file as `layouts.app` instead of `Layouts.app` then there is bound to be an error.

Answer (score -2):

I faced this problem too and much try to fix it after that I find an error and it was very minor :) ... just check your layout folder spelling. In the blade file "@extends('layouts. app')" written like that "layouts" and we make a folder in view name as layout.

Comment: This question was already answered and accepted. Why you added this answer, it doesn't add anything useful or extra to the previously accepted answer.